# Have an image that won't show up on certain resolutions

Tags: html, css, image, footer

Here is my website: http://www.bkd.com/wealth-advisors/index-test.htm

The problem I am currently having is that the "Wisdom for Your Wealth" bar will only show up on certain resolutions. Is there anyway I can make this show up on all? I need it to lay across the page the same on every page. A little below the bottom but not all the way at the bottom.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Here is my CSS:

```
.bottombar {
    position:fixed;
    margin-top: 800px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    height:42px;
    width:1800px;
    z-index:100;
       }
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:-50; left:5; font-size:80px; z-index:4"><a   
href="/wealth-advisors/about-test.htm"><img src="/wealth-advisors/images/wisdom-
wealth.png" height="52" width="800" class="bottombar" ></a></div>
```

Please let me know if you need anything else from me.

Thank you!
-Marcy-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your problem:

```
.bottombar {
   bottom: 0;
   display: table;
   height: auto;
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
}
```

With `width: 100%`, `position: absolute` and `display: table` you don't need to adjust top, left or any margins.

Comment: Thank you @ProgramFOX and @Jordana-morais! This works great, any suggestions on how to make it show up for IE9?

Comment: Change the `display: table` to `display: block` and will work fine on IE and other browsers

Comment: Hey @Jordana-morais i have noticed that the bottom bar that you helped with works on my resolution but when i look at it on a bigger resolution or smaller it isn't stayed directly at the bottom it scrolls with the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: The problem seems to be with `<img>` and `<p>` tags inside `#container` .

Try this adjustments:

`#container {
    float: left;
    height: 656px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}`

and

`#text {
    background: url("/wealth-advisors/images/hp-copy.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 40px auto;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    width: 610px;
}`

and remove the `<img>` before `<p id="text">`

Answer (score 0):

use `bottom:0;` i would may try removing the margin top as well. i would change the width to 100%. also remember you have the image in a div that's absolute and the image is fixed.